# Ruby ZIP file encoding for sending to Sidekiq / Redis

Tags: ruby, encoding, redis, sidekiq

I build a ZIP file using the following code:

```
def compress_batch(directory_path)
  zip_file_path = File.join( File.expand_path("..", directory_path), SecureRandom.hex(10))
  Zip::File.open(zip_file_path, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zip_file|
    (Dir.entries(directory_path) - %w(. ..)).each do |file_name|
      zip_file.add file_name, File.join(directory_path, file_name)
    end
  end

  result = File.open(zip_file_path, 'rb').read
  File.unlink(zip_file_path)
  result
end
```

I store that ZIP file in memory:

```
@result = Payoff::DataFeed::Compress::ZipCompress.new.compress_batch(source_path)
```

I put it into a hash:

```
options = {
  data: @result
}
```

Then I submit it to my SideKiq worker using `perform_async`:

```
DeliveryWorker.perform_async(options)
```

and get the following error:

```
[DEBUG]   Starting store to: { "destination" => "sftp", "path" => "INBOUND/20191009.zip" }
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xBA" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
from ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:34:in `encode'
```

However, if I use `.new.perform` instead of `.perform_async`, bypassing SideKiq, it works fine!

```
DeliveryWorker.new.perform(options)
```

My best guess is that there is something wrong with my encoding such that when the job goes to SideKiq / Redis, it blows up.  How should I have encoded it?  Do I need to change the creation of my ZIP file?  Maybe I can convert the encoding upon submission to SideKiq?

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple It works when you do `.new.perform` because nothing gets serialized to JSON and pushed to Redis -- the job is called directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sidekiq serializes arguments as JSON. You are trying to stuff binary data into JSON, which only supports UTF-8 strings.  You will need to Base64 encode the data if you wish to pass it through Redis.

```
require 'base64'

encoded = Base64.encode64(filedata)
```